# 重用 - Reading Preference

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation, dialects, spoken-language, written-language

Reading some 読解 Material I stumbled upon the word 重用. I read it as じゅうよう without much attention, only to notice that the furigana on top read "ちょうよう". Searching a bit on dictionaries I saw that actually both readings are acceptable, and actually a native speaker on Forvo chose to read it as "じゅうよう".

Why does an official text from a newspaper have the furigana "ちょうよう" then? Is it a matter of Dialect? Spoken vs written Language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, today both are acceptable but ちょうよう is more authentic according to web sources (e.g. [this](https://business-textbooks.com/chouhuku-jyuuhuku/)). That should be why it was used in the newspaper. There is no difference in nuance/meaning.

The original reading of 重用 is ちょうよう, but more and more people use じゅうよう most probably because じゅう for 重 is more common (e.g., 重要{じゅうよう}, 重大{じゅうだい}, 重機{じゅうき}). As a result, じゅうよう became a conventional reading for 重用.

---

FYI The same is true for 重複, whose original reading is ちょうふく and じゅうふく is another accepted reading. I believe most dictionaries list both readings for such words (e.g, [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%87%8D%E7%94%A8_%28%E3%81%98%E3%82%85%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%29/#jn-104698)).